# What is Composite Document File V2 Document?

Tags: linux, file, ms-word, document

I need to write a script to find out if a given document is of the format .doc or not.
Iam using Amazon Linux machine. I tried to make use of the linux file command.
For a given doc file the file command outputs the file information as following:

**sample_file.doc: Composite Document File V2 Document, No summary info**

I found out that file command provides the same file type information for 2003 excel files (.xls).

I want to know what all file types (like doc,xls) come under Composite Document File V2 Document and how I can check if given file is a doc file or not in Amazon Linux 2012 machine?

Answer (score 8):

It is a document format of the Microsoft. I used the guide [here](http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-convert-documents-between-libreoffice-and-microsoft-office-file-formats-on-linux) to convert my files without issues.

Essentially, you can use the `unoconv` tool for the conversion to a more friendly format.

Comment: The Composite Document Files (CDF) supported by `unoconv` is a miniscule fraction of the files that can, and do, have such format. That Excel and some other Office applications store file in a CDF doesn't mean that every CDF is an Office file.

Comment: For example, the Microsoft Windows Movie Maker file format (.MSWMM) uses CDF.

Comment: I have a `.db` file which `file` believes is a CDF v2, even `unoconv` cant read it. In any case, unoconv is deprecated, use [unoserver](https://github.com/unoconv/unoserver/), or just `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf MyDocument.odf`